# Linux userspace header failing to compile with g++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have a cpp source file in which I have included the following Linux uapi header:

`#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4/ip_tables.h>`

I'm using RH6, but the header seems to be identical to the one found in the Linux kernel mainline: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ip_tables.h

The problem is that upon compiling my cpp source file with g++, I'm (obviously) receiving the following error:

`/usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ip_tables.h:222: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'xt_entry_target*'`

I know I can surpass it with `-fpermissive` flag, but that is hardly a solution.

Also, I tried surrounding the inclusion in an `extern "C" {}` block (which as far as I understand should make the compiler see everything inside it as C code and allow the implicit conversion), but the error does not go away.

How does a C++ program deal with this kind of C incompatibilities? (where one cannot directly edit the source causing trouble)

Comment: "should make the compiler see everything inside it as C code" - NO! C++ is not C is not C++! `extern "C"` jut tells the C++ compiler to use the C ABI. The code is still interpreted as C++ code. In principle there could be a `extern "fortran"` construct as well; the code still had to be C++.

Comment: I think you will need to push/pop the warning(s) around the header file #include .  See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas

Comment: Without looking at your source I can only ask - Why don't you cast it explicitly (if such a conversion is required)?

Comment: @Olaf: yes I know C++ is not C, I just thought it would allow the implicit conversion.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Because it's not OP's code; it's a system header.

Comment: @Olaf is C ABI a valid term? I don't think the standard imposes any ABI. ABI is decided by the platform and the target as far as I know. The name mangling is different for C and C++ and that is one thing extern "C" indicates to the compiler.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya because I have no control whatsoever over the header file. I just want to include it. I don't want to convert nothing. But the inline function at line 222 does this and therefore my whole source does not compile

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: The ABI is part of the implementation - apparently. The standard very well talks about the implementation. You could also use "C calling conventions". All this is covered by `extern "C"`. ABI was just the most obvious part.

Comment: @Melpomene Oh I get it. I thought he was including a header and calling a function from it.

Comment: @Olaf Objection is - Does any platform have different ABIs for programs compiled with C, C++ Fortran or even assembly? *I think*, C ABI is a non term. I might be wrong there.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Intel, ARM, Linux, Microsoft and many other CPU and OS vendors think different. While most C++ ABIs build on C ABIs, there are significant differences, e.g. for exception frames and other constructs. Maybe you have stumbled opon the difference between e.g. C and Pascal calling conventions (which are part of the ABI). Same for Fortran, of course! "I think" i not a valid objection. Would be good to first dig deeper; I will reply even if a comment was not instantly posted, but after some research and better padded with facts.

Comment: @Olaf, okay so it means "Use C version of the ABI for the platform and target and not the C++ version". There is nothing as Standard C ABI. Is it correctly worded?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Please read the standard and learn the rest. No offence, but you lack the whole picture. The ABIs for x86, x64, ARM, etc. are freely available, the same for the final draft of both, the C as well the C++ standards. That's something every C and C++ programmer should know (or at least be aware of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the following preprocessing statements:

```
#if __GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 2) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ == 2 && __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ > 3)
    #if __GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 6) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ == 6 && __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ > 3)
         #pragma GCC diagnostic push
    #endif

    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-fpermissive"

    #include <linux/netfilter_ipv4/ip_tables.h>

    #if __GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 6) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ == 6 && __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ > 3)
         #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    #endif
#else
    #error at least GCC 4.2.4 is required
#endif
```

Used the documentation available at: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas

It takes into consideration that Diagnostic Pragmas were introduced in GCC 4.2.4 and the support for push/pop operations for these pragmas was introduced in GCC 4.6.4.

Currently I'm compiling with 4.4.7 so the pragma takes effect for the whole translation unit, but at least it does not force me to supply the flag when invoking the compiler.

Thanks to @Richard Critten for pointing me  into the right direction.